# what is the syntax for insert trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert, syntax

I am very new to sql. feel a little stupid to ask this question

Say I have this table `Warehouse(shipperid, name , state)`. Then I define another table `warehouse_maine (shipperid, name, state)` which should only contain the warehouse located in maine. after I insert all the data for warehouse. I want to create a trigger for `warehouse_maine`, which insert the warehouse data only in maine state.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER01 ON WAREHOUSE_MAINE
FOR INSERT
AS select * from warehouse where warehouse.state= maine
```

This is what I thought but it's obviously wrong. what should be the syntax after keyword AS?

Comment: Why would you need 2 tables to contain the same duplicate information?

Comment: It is a practice for trigger

Comment: what dbms do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to actually do the INSERT into `warehouse_maine` after `Warehouse`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Warehouse_InsertAfter $$
CREATE TRIGGER Warehouse_InsertAfter AFTER INSERT ON Warehouse
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.state = 'maine' THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO warehouse_maine (shipperid, name, state)
        VALUES (NEW.shipperid, NEW.name, NEW.state);
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger will do the job. If you are doing a bulk `INSERT` of rows into the `Warehouse` table, this trigger will slow things down a bit. If you plan to do such bulk `INSERT`s, you are better off doing that in a single `INSERT`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO warehouse_maine
SELECT * FROM Warehouse WHERE state='maine';
```

Comment: this works! thank you very much! The only confusion is what is IGNORE stands for?

Comment: I used `INSERT IGNORE` in case the record for 'maine' was already there in `warehouse_maine`. This prevents entire duplicate `shipperid` values.